# Packaging WPF and UWP apps with the one installer

Tags: .net, wpf, uwp

Have both WPF and UWP applications that I would like to install with the one installer.  I don’t want to go down the migration path of converting the WPF too UWP with the desktop bridge, not at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

There is some guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) that hopefully will help you to package UWP and WPF.

Comment: After many hours of searching and fighting against the obvious thinking that hours of design time was going to go down the toilet I finally tried WPF to UWP conversion path.  Expecting the output to be butchered, I was pleasantly surprised when everything still looked as it should and worked as expected. Had a problem converting the wpf setup.exe with the converter app finding the exe file.  But when I created an msi install version from source the converter app was able to convert everything, no problems.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: please mark that as the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.